# Display computed results in child component in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I pull data in from an Axios request. I have approx 500 records each with several results. I have simplified it for ease.

I display the data on the main component as a drop-down menu and it displays one entry for 'John' and one for 'Jane'. It splits the JSON data and removes duplicates and this works fine.

What Im stuck with is how to display the same data in the child component. At the moment it just displays 'Jane,Jane,Jane,John,John,John,Jane,'.

Do I have to do another methods in the child component for this? I can pass in a prop with uniquenames but it just displays them all in each result.

Any help would be most appreciated.

JSON

```json
"results": [
  "result": {
    "name": "Jane,Jane,John,John,John,John,Jane,Jane,"
  }
  "result": {
    "name": "Jane,Jane,Jane,John,John,John,Jane,"
  }
  "result": {
    "name": "John,Jane,"
  }
  "result": {
    "name": "Jane"
  }
]
```

**Main component**

```html
<Result
  v-for="result in Results"
  :result="result"
  :key="result.docNum"
/>

<ul v-for="name in uniquenames" :key="name">
  <li>
  <label class="pr-2" for="name">{{ name }}</label>
  <input                           
    type="checkbox"
    v-model="names"
    :value="name"                             
  />
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
methods: {
  const metanames = this.Results
    .filter((result) => results.result && results.result.name)
    .map((item) => item.name)
    .filter((names, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(names) === i)
          
  let names = []
  metanames.forEach((item) => {
    const splitArr = item.split(', ')
    names = names.concat(splitArr)
  })

  this.uniquenames = names.filter(
    (names, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(names) === i,
  )
}
```

**Child component**

```html
<template>
  <div>                
    {{ name }}
  </div> 
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "result", 
    
  props: {
    result: Object,     
  },
      
  data: function () {
    return {       
      name: this.results.result.name
    }
  }
```

Comment: where is the child component used in the template? what does the original array of names look like when fetched from the API?  please share more code.  from what I can guess right now, I think the child component receives the full array of names when you mean to only send a single name? so you should send a single name, not the full array.  Or, you want to display all the names in the child component individually but you're displaying them all in a single div when you need another `v-for` loop

Comment: Thank you. I want to send the data to the child component that removes the duplicates. Just now it shows 'Jane,Jane,John,John,John,John,Jane,Jane' in the child. I have removed the duplicates in the main component using a method called 'uniquenames'. I cant work out how to pass this onto the child, so that the duplicates are removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<Result>` component in the Parent template is passing in the items of `Result` in a loop, but you have not modified `Result`, hence why the original non-unique array of names is passed in.  Create and pass down a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example) instead which should be a modified version of `Result` in the format you want.  A computed property can update/reformat automatically whenever its dependencies (the original `Result`) changes.  Whenever the computed property updates so will the prop

```html
<Result
  v-for="result in modifiedResults"
  :result="result"
  :key="result.docNum"
/>
```

```js
computed: {
    modifiedResults() {
      // unfinished code for returning modified Results containing array of unique names
      return [...this.Results].map(r => {
        let uniquenames = getUniqueNames(r.names)
        return { ...r, names: uniquenames }
      })
    },
  },
```

as the comment says you'll need to finish/change the computed property to return exactly what you want. I can't do it as I'm not completely sure how all the different arrays and object properties in your code fit together, but computed property is definitely the way to go!